# Adding buffer to tracklog in real-time in ArcPad?

Tags: arcpad, tracklog

- Hardware: Trimble Juno T41/5
- Software: ArcPad 10.2

I am looking for a method or plugin for ArcPad that will help with spraying for noxious weed control, specifically a way to add a "boom width" buffer to a track log and display it in real time. This plugin should allow the user to identify gaps and overlap in chemical application. I know there are several stand alone systems that do similar functions but I already own the Trimble handheld and don't really want to spend more for a very basic function.

Comment: I should add that I have searched Google extensively and found little to nothing. I have also tried to find away to add a buffer to the tracklog symbology, but I can't find a way to make it display in real time. 

Does ArcPad have many auxiliary plugins for specific functions? I use QGIS as a desktop platform so I'm a little out of my element with this handheld.

Comment: Given the paucity of answers I am going to attempt to write a VBscript for ArcPad to do what I described above. I have nearly zero experience with coding but have been researching the last couple days and think I should be able to figure it out. Does anybody have a VBscript example that would work to take GPS points at a specified time interval? That should serve as a starting point, from which I should be able to add additional functions that I need.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with improvements to your original question such as this: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115